# How do I validate forms and present error messages using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, validation, server-side

Let's say we have this form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

How do I validate this form using submit.php, and how do I present an error message if it doesn't pass validation? With Javascript validation I would just change the innerHTML of some element to the error message, but this is not possible with PHP. As you can see I'm a total newbie, so please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ugly form:

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username)) {
       $errors[] = "Please enter your username";
    }
    if (empty($pw)) {
       $errors[] = "Please provide your password";
    }
    if (!canLogin($username, $pw)) {
       $errors[] = "Invalid login. Try again";
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
       ... login is ok, go do something else
    }
}

# Display error conditions, if there are any
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    echo "<p>The following errors must be corrected:</p><ul><li>";
    echo implode("</li><li>", $errors);
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>

<form ...>
<input .... value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username) ?>" />
<input ...>
</form>
```

Comment: If I use echo, then the error message will be displayed at the end of the page, right?                                                              What does !canLogin() mean? What does implode mean?

Comment: No. it's echoed into the page right where the php code is. in this case, immediately before the form tag.

Comment: What do !canLogin() and implode() mean?

Comment: http://php.net/implode, and canLogin is an imaginary function to show where should you do the actual real "can this user log in" checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the form's action submit to itself (same PHP script) and perform your validation there and if it passes continue to another url.  And then in your form write some conditionals to insert a CSS class to highlight the field thats in error or show a message.